# jQuery - z-index manipulation & auto value instead number

Tags: jquery, z-index

When you clik on `add new` button, jQuery inserts new `dragrable DIVs` to the `CONTAINER`. When I click on some of this `DIVs`, I want to change `z-index` value. But jQuery can't get z-index value as a number. It shows just `'auto'`... Is there solution to show true z-index value and `increase it by 1` ?

jsFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/84nVQ/10/

**HTML**

```
<div id="add" style="background:yellow; width:100px;"> add new </div>
<div id="container"> </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function handler() {
    if ($(this).find("#menu").length) {
        return;
    }
    var currentIndex = $(this).css('z-index');
    alert(currentIndex);
    var newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    alert(newIndex);
    $(this).css('z-index', newIndex);
}
$("#add").on({
    click: function(e) {
        var timestamp = Date.now();
        var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        $('#container').append(function() {
            return $('<div class="add_to_this" id="' + timestamp + '" style="left:' + posx + 'px; top:' + posy + 'px; ">Click me, drag a change z-index</div>').click(handler).draggable({
                containment: "#container",
                scroll: false,
                cursor: 'lock'
        });
    });
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background: palegoldenrod;
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.add_to_this {
    padding:5px;
    background:yellowgreen;
    position: absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems in your code :

- you don't have a real `z-index` to start with because you didn't set it, so you have `'auto'`
- you manipulate the `z-index` as string because you don't parse it

What you need to do :

- add in the css a `z-index` :     `z-index:100;`
- parse the `z-index` : `var currentIndex = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);`

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7c7e/) (without the alerts as they were annoying)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, is there a solution how to fix it ? Some example, or can you show it in jsfiddle example ? Because I don't know what you meant...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your example is working fine :]

Comment: Just for fun I made a few changes (colors, cursor). Check it out ;)

Comment: nice :] I'm trying manually to change background color with miniColor plugin. I can't solve it... I'm new in jQuery... http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/m7c7e/1/

Comment: While this works, it's not very practical. As if you redrag the element that is already on top the z-index keeps increasing. Meaning you need to drag the lower element a greater number of times to bring it to the top.